# I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Asus tuf gaming A15 laptop (2023), the keyboard not work

Tags: keyboard, asus

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Asus tuf gaming A15 laptop (2023), the keyboard does not work, apparently there is no support for new types of keyboards in the Linux kernel, can you help solve this problem